# Modifying Audio System Settings via console in OpenSUSE 13.1

Tags: terminal, audio, opensuse

My PC has an internal speaker and every time when I reboot `linux`, the output of the (integrated) sound card changes to this internal speaker. But I want to use my external speakers (via the green jack hole), so every time at system start I have to change it manually via the graphical interface:

`System Settings` -> `Multimedia` icon -> `Audio and Video Settings` item (left) -> `Audio Hardware Setup` tab -> `Connector list`

and change

`Speakers` -> `Line Out`

I want to automate it, but the first step is doing this action via terminal. Can you help me how can I change the connector via `terminal`?

I am using OpenSUSE 13.1 (kernel: 3.11.10-21-desktop), using Phonon multimedia framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound in Linux is done via alsa (or pulse audio); however, by default OpenSuSE uses alsa.

Luckily, you can set your defaults as a regular user through `alsamixer`. Simply run that, select which channel you want as the master, and exit.

You should be able to hear sound through your default channel (you may need to restart alsa with `systemctl restart alsa-restore`).

When you reboot, your setting should still be there.